# Fuzzy Logic . How to get the complement

Tags: complement, fuzzy-logic

i came across the following fuzzy logic example about fuzzy logic.

Representing Age
Problem 2-1. Fuzzy sets can be used to represent fuzzy concepts. Let U be a reasonable age interval of human beings.

U = {0, 1, 2, 3, ... , 100}

Solution 2-1. This interval can be interpreted with fuzzy sets by setting the universal space for age to range from 0 to 100.

Problem 2-2. Assume that the concept of "young" is represented by a fuzzy set Young, whose membership function is given by the following fuzzy set.

**Young= FuzzyTrapeZoid [0 ,0 ,25 ,40]**

All i want to understand is how i can get the **Complement[Young]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that Complement[Young] = FuzzyTrapeZoid[25,40,100,100]. Here is an image to show (in red) Young, and the complement in green.
[image]

Were you looking for an algorithm to solve this?

**edit**: adding more:

A generic fuzzy trapezoid is: `FuzzyTrapeZoid[A,B,C,D]`

[image]

The membership value is 0 up to A, then ramps from 0 to 1 between A and B, stays at 1 from B to C, then ramps from 1 to 0 between C and D. [see page 3 of this intro](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~sxp/DSM/fuzzy_sets_intro.pdf) (warning! pdf)

Since the complement of a fuzzy set = `1 - the membership function`, then you can pretty much see the values by inspection. For the original problem (which comes from [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/fuzzylogic/examples/age.html)), the complement is a single function. For the generic one  `FuzzyTrapeZoid[A,B,C,D]` you will need 2 trapeziods to make the complement: `FuzzyTrapeZoid[0,0,A,B] +  FuzzyTrapeZoid[C,D,100,100]`

For the Young membership function, it is 1 up to 25, so the complement will be 0 up to 25 (this yields [25,x,x,x] where x is yet to be determined). Since the Young membership function ramps to 0 between 25 and 40, it is clear that the complement will ramp from 0 to 1 in the same range (this yields the [25,40,x,x] where x is yet to be determined). Finally, since the Young membership function is 0 from 40 to 100, the complement will be 1 in the same range, this gives [x,40,100,100] (we knew from before that x = 25).

If you were looking for some more formal proof, I'm sorry, I do proofs poorly as I come from the Captain Kirk school of math: I can see it, and I can jump to the right answer, but I can't tell you exactly how I did it.

Comment: hi, Thanks for the answer.But i actually want to know how you got the values of the complement[young]. Like the formula + explanation for that. Where did you derive the values 25,40,100

Comment: To calculate the complement of a fuzzy set membership, subtract the original value from 1.0.